# Azure Application insight Query Merge rows

Tags: azure-application-insights

I have following query:

```
traces
| where customDimensions.Category == "Function"
| where isnotempty(customDimensions.prop__recordId) or isnotempty(customDimensions.prop__Entity)
| project operation_Id, Entity = customDimensions.prop__Entity, recordName = customDimensions.prop__recordName, recordId = customDimensions.prop__recordId
```

I get results like these:
[image]
I want to merge rows by operation_id, and get results like these:
[image]

Comment: Have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try use join operator, like below:

```
traces
| where customDimensions.Category == "Function"
| where isnotempty(customDimensions.prop__recordId) 
| project operation_Id, customDimensions.prop__recordId
| join kind = inner(
traces
| where customDimensions.Category == "Function"
| where isnotempty(customDimensions.prop__Entity)
| project operation_Id,customDimensions.prop__Entity,customDimensions.prop__recordName
) on operation_Id
| project-away operation_Id1 //remove the redundant column,note that it's operation_Id1 
| project operation_Id, Entity = customDimensions.prop__Entity, recordName = customDimensions.prop__recordName, recordId = customDimensions.prop__recordId
```

I did not has the same data, but make some similar data, works fine at my side.

**Before merge:**

[image]

**After merge:(and note that use project-away to remove the redundant column which is used as joined key, and it always has number suffix 1 by default)**

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ivan due to your solution I build query which works traces. Notice that Query builder forced me to change some props at the end, for example  customDimensions.prop__recordName was changed to customDimensions_prop__recordName

Comment: @SergeyAslanov, Glad that you solved your issue. And it would be better if you mark my post as an answer, I just need some rep. But it doesn't matter if you don't like that.

Comment: Sorry, I marked two and only one answer is allowed ;)

Answer (score 0):

Final query is:

```
| where customDimensions.Category == "Function"
| where isnotempty(customDimensions.prop__recordId)
| project operation_Id, customDimensions.prop__recordId
| join kind = inner(
traces
| where customDimensions.Category == "Function"
| where isnotempty(customDimensions.prop__Entity)
| project operation_Id,customDimensions.prop__Entity
) on operation_Id
| join kind = inner(
traces
| where customDimensions.Category == "Function"
| where isnotempty(customDimensions.prop__recordName)
| project operation_Id,customDimensions.prop__recordName
) on operation_Id
| project operation_Id, Entity = customDimensions_prop__Entity, recordName = customDimensions_prop__recordName, recordId = customDimensions_prop__recordId
```